# update database migration plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, upgrade, database-migration

I am trying to use [database-migration:1.4.0](https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) but unfortunately I got  in [this jira issue](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1163) it is mentioned that the issuse is resolved in `Liquibase 3.x` version so I need to updated the liquibase version in db migration plugin because currently the plugin uses `Liquibase version: 2.0.5`, how can I update liquibase version in the plugin.thanks

Comment: literally you can't. There is no configuration option or something. The only thing that currently works is, that there not yet official version of the database-migration plugin in the making, that uses Liquibase 3 - but that is only working with grails 3 as well. You'll find the plugin at [bintray](https://bintray.com/yamkazu/plugins/org.grails.plugins%3Adatabase-migration/view) and [here](https://github.com/yamkazu/database-migration) is the github repo. If you have to stick to Grails 2 for now, i think you have to use plain liquibase without the database-migration wrapper.